Seeking Efficient Use of json_serializable with Generics in Dart for export models in a package/library
I am currently using json_serializable with generic objects in Dart, where the generics should freezed classes (have toJson methos and fromJson constructor). I have a working implementation, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient or cleaner way to achieve this.
I have a package with some models that accept generics, so I want to export it but need an easy way to people set the behavior of the serialization in a easy way, The ideal solution is that they didn't have to do anything.
In my current approach, I assume that every object has a toJson method. I also maintain a global mutable variable fromJsonFactories, where the corresponding fromJson is assigned for each type. I've seen generic_argument_factories, but it seems to add a lot of boilerplate for each implementation.
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation:
// Override this map with the factories for the types you want to deserialize.
// Example:
// fromJsonFactories = {
//  ModelA: (json) => ModelA.fromJson(json),
// };
Map<Type, Object Function(Map<String, dynamic> json)> fromJsonFactories = {};

class GenericJsonConverter<T> implements JsonConverter<T, Object?> {
  const GenericJsonConverter();

  @override
  T fromJson(Object? json) {
    return fromJsonFactories[T]!(json as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
  }

  @override
  Object? toJson(T object) {
    return (object as dynamic).toJson();
  }
}

For now whoever uses the models from my package/library has to override fromJsonFactories in the main.
The idea would be that they didn't have to do anything.
I initially tried to avoid using a global variable, as I know all classes will have a factory fromJson. However, this approach resulted in an error:
  @override
  T fromJson(Object? json) {
    // Error: Class 'Type' has no instance method 'fromJson'.
    return (T as dynamic).fromJson() as T;
  }

You can find the full example of my current implementation in this gist.
Any suggestions for improving this implementation would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Unfortunately, Dart does not support dispatching a function call based on a Type and for your solution to work you need a mapping from Type to fromJsonFactory.
To make it easier for users of your package I would suggest storing the fromJson factories as a static variable and defining a static function to register types with GenericJsonConverter.
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'generic_json_serializable_converter_test.freezed.dart';
part 'generic_json_serializable_converter_test.g.dart';

typedef FromJsonFactory<T> = T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json);

class GenericJsonConverter<T> implements JsonConverter<T, Object?> {
  const GenericJsonConverter();

  static final Map<Type, FromJsonFactory> _fromJsonFactories = {};

  @override
  T fromJson(Object? json) {
    return _fromJsonFactories[T]!(json as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
  }

  /// Registers a FromJsonFactory with return type `T`. 
  static register<T>(FromJsonFactory<T> fromJsonFactory) {
    _fromJsonFactories[T] = fromJsonFactory;
  }

  @override
  Object? toJson(T object) {
    return (object as dynamic).toJson();
  }
}

To register a FromJsonFactory one would then use:
void main() {
  GenericJsonConverter.register<ModelA>((json) => ModelA.fromJson(json));
}

